# Insert class "form-group-row" into "form-horizontal"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the code - http://www.bootply.com/h0E7YjPU4n.

1. How to make space between input fields of the same height?
2. How to make input fields of the same length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to wrap the `.input-group` in a `col-sm-5`. See this bootply: http://www.bootply.com/OvEfUMhoG7.

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">kg</div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```